# Apache: require ldap group or htgroup membership

Tags: apache, ldap, .htpasswd

I'm working on transitioning our users from htpasswd/htgroup auth to ldap.

While this in progress, I want to allow Apache to authorise users from both ldap and htpasswd.

I have the following in my config...

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap file

AuthUserFile my_passwords
AuthGroupFile my_groups

AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Bind User,OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dir.mydomain.com/OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=User)"
```

I'm not sure how to combine both require types...

So basically I need to require either one of these...

```
Require ldap-group CN=MyGroup,OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

or

```
Require group MyGroup
```

If I use "Satisfy any", then the Requires are basically ignored. If I use "Satisfy all", then only the ldap-group membership works.

Is there any way to get around this, so membership in either htgroups, or ldap groups works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just in case it's useful to anyone else. I had to add the following directives...

```
AuthzGroupFileAuthoritative off
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
```

This allowed it to verify the group with the groupfile if it wasn't found in ldap, and vice-versa.